# SQL Case When Statement Mismatched result

Tags: sql, case

I have this query, and I would like to understand why the result2 generates more 1s than result1. I would expect the result of the query to generate identical results meaning result1=result2. I would appreciate if someone can help understand

```
case
    when item1 = 1 and category = 'Category1' then 1
    when item2 = 1 and category = 'Category2' then 1
    when item3 = 1 and category = 'Category3' then 1
    when item4 = 1 and category = 'Category4' then 1
    else 0
end as result1,
case
when ((item1 = 1 and category = 'Category1')
    or (item2 = 1 and category = 'Category2')
    or (item3 = 1 and category = 'Category3')
    or (item4 = 1 and category = 'Category4')) then 1
    else 0
end as result2,
```

Comment: Show us one row that differs.

Comment: @jarlh I have slightly updated the code to reflect the truth. But basically in case when I have item1=0, item2=0, item3=1, item4=1 and category = "category 2" I still get 1 as a result

Comment: I wouldn't expect the queries to generate _identical_ results, since the second query can fall prey to nulls - if e.g. `item2` is nullable and null, the result will always be 0, regardless of the category. This would cause result2 to have _fewer_ 1s, of course.

Comment: @Luaan in this specific case there are no nulls, its either 0 or 1 for item fields and text for category

Comment: Make sure the code you're posting is exactly the same as the one you're testing. There might be a typo somewhere, or missing parenthesis for example.

Comment: @Luaan its the code I used, and I tried to review and see if i am missing something but no

Comment: @Luaan . . . The two versions should treat `NULL`s the same way.  There should be no difference in the results.  The OP has oversimplified the code.